# Resizing a PNG with minimal distortion

Tags: png, resize

I am trying to resize this image:

[image]

The image is 73x44 and I would like to resize it down to 53x32.

First, I tried using Photoshop CS6 with different resampling algorithms using the `Image size` dialog:

Bicubic automatic:
[image]

Bicubic: [image]

Bilinear: [image]

Nearest neighbor: [image]

They all look pretty bad, especially that the border on the left, right and bottom are more pronounced, but the border on top has almost disappeared.

I then tried [picresize](http://www.picresize.com) and the result was pretty good and did not have that much distortion:
[image]

What settings should I adjust in Photoshop to be able to yield the same resize quality as picresize?

Comment: Two related questions: [How to resize icon sets in Photoshop](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/how-to-resize-icon-sets-in-photoshop), and [Scaling down images and the impact on image quality](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15283/scaling-down-images-and-the-impact-on-image-quality)

Answer (score 3):

It usually is hard trying to adjust pixels that small.  After creating a lot of eCommerce site designs I decided to create every credit card in an Illustrator template so that I could scale it for such a purpose and reuse it as I see fit.

If you are worried about quality re-creating the credit card would be your best option.  There is two ways you can do this.

1. Entirely in Illustrator (the best choice).
2. Using Photoshop but with an `.eps` Visa logo (example below).

### Photoshop Tutorial:

1. Create the desired finish size.
2. Download the Visa logo as an `.eps`.  I prefer and found all the logos at [Logoeps.com](http://www.logoeps.com/) and I used this [Visa Logo](http://www.logoeps.com/visa-vector-logo/3584/).
3. Create a layer and add the credit card above.
4. Lock layer with credit card.
5. Create a new layer.
6. Place guides for the correct scaling of the logo and resize the `.eps` logo.
7. Create a new layer and place that layer below the `.eps` logo.
8. With the `rounded rectangle tool` create the background.
9. Use the color picker tool and grab the top and bottom colors and add them to your swatch palette.  Also use the `color picker tool` and grab the blue Visa color.
10. Go to `blending options > gradient` and add the top and bottom colors, make sure to use the `Linear Gradient`.  That should create the gradient needed.
11. Go to `stroke` use the Visa color you previously selected and set it to `1 px` for the size and change the position to `inside`.
12. Unlock the last layer with the image we used as a template.
13. Delete the image layer.

You should have nice Visa credit card.